# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Binary'

Tags: python, pickle, xml-rpc

I use `xmlrpc.server` to build a server and use `pickle.dumps()` to pickling some data. Then I use `xmlrpc.client` to build a client and use `pickle.loads()` to unpickle this data.

```py
## server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('0.0.0.0', 5005), allow_none=True)
# in _dispatch method:
result = perform_stuff()
return pickle.dumps(result)

## client
proxy = ServerProxy(f'http://{host}:{port}', allow_none=True)
result = proxy.make_rpc()
return pickle.loads(result.data)
```

However, I counter the following problems:

I don't know the difference between the bytes-like object and 'Binary'
[image]

I try to use bytes(ret) to solve this problem, but it has another one

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry that the source code is really so big and can't show that here.

Comment: @lxg_april That's why you should try to isolate the issue and paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `Binary` instance `bin`, you can get the data as a `bytes` or `bytearray` instance by `bin.data`.

I can only guess from the code snippet you provided, but the following should work:

```
ret = pickle.loads(ret.data)
```

Comment: I have tried that and I think it really works!Thank you very much!